# Using relational algebra to find the largest occurence of something?

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra

I have a relation:

Person: **day, person**, wentToClass(boolean)

Without loss of generality, there can't be two rows with the same day for the same person.

I have to use relational algebra to find the person who wentToClass the most.

A.k.a the person who has more occurences of wentToClass=True in comparsion to every other person.

I tried many things involving cartesian prods, but I can't really seem to be able to find a pattern. I was thinking about using intersection. But I failed.

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried so far.  It is possible that it could be improved on.

Comment: As I said, I tried using cartesian product to join the table to itself and try to find some pattern that I could use. But I have been stuck there for a while.

What differs from other problems like finding the highest value of something is that here I can't really use > or < operators because I am dealing with booleans.

Comment: It is a whole lot easier for people to help you if you show what you have done so far.

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29897/use-count-in-relational-algebra for using aggregate functions in relational algebra.  A left outer self-join of the aggregated counts on a.count < b.count will allow you to find the counts which aren't less than any other.

Comment: @reaanb I am assuming this is unsolvable using the common Project, Select and Set operations in a non-extended relational algebra model because of the fact that comparisons need to be done with numbers...

Comment: @DMan It can be done using a natural join of max and count aggregated relations grouped on person, but you can't do it without aggregate functions and they're not part of the basic relational algebra.

Comment: Please give example uses of exactly the operators you can use and/or a reference to the particular version of relational algebra that you are supposed to use.

Comment: The difficulty is not the booleans. After you restrict to to rows with TRUE, you don't need to compare values. The difficulty is calculating which person has more rows. You are confusing querying about a maximum value in a column vs about the maximum number of rows per candidate key in a column.